# Why is this typescript type annotation required in a generic function?

Tags: typescript, type-inference

Tried to boil it down to a minimal, contrived example below ([ts playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DCB7AtgB2xAnAAUpt8BnAHgEkAaZAFQD5kBvAKGWQBM4YOAC5kdANoBdANw9kIAK4AbJQCVBwbABFBcABTBRdAJSjxzJnrCjmx5AF52AN2zA+MrgF8uXPhARKcFAoMAogCGCaIGhYeITE4PRMbHow2NiiGDgERCRg5JS0jCyspjHZ8XkF1EklsghEVGDIcA7lcbngety8AkJmAIxMAExMAMySDHIA9NPIAOoAFujIwFTIYIsoAAaKuABG0NstICDYQpFEyMEAjgrAwXwA-HKKKuqXOv3IeiCie4coHZHMhxCAAHRgbAAZTAUFAAHM9MZLFRgewqOClCQEZtJl5jNIgA))

```
interface MyComponentProps<I, T> {
  data: I[];
  getter(i: I): [T, (t: T) => number];
}

declare function MyComponent<I, T>(arg: MyComponentProps<I, T>): MyComponentProps<I, T>;

const comp = MyComponent({
  data: [1, 2, 3],
  // Why is the `number` annotation required?
  getter: (n: number) => [n.toString(), (s) => s.length],
});
```

If you [remove](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DCB7AtgB2xAnAAUpt8BnAHgEkAaZAFQD5kBvAKGWQBM4YOAC5kdANoBdANw9kIAK4AbJQCVBwbABFBcABTBRdAJSjxzJnrCjmx5AF52AN2zA+MrgF8uXPhARKcFAoMAogCGCaIGhYeITE4PRMbHow2NiiGDgERCRg5JS0jCyspjHZ8XkF1EklsghEVGDIcA7lcbngety8AkJmAIxMAExMAMySDHIA9NPIAKJQFFDIAO7AYAAW2ArNWyhg6PgocCAg2EKRRMjXIHKKKupXOv3IeiB2jsjiIAB0YNgAMpgKCgADmemMlion3YVF+ShIYK2ky8xmkQA) the `number` type annotation from the `getter` implementation then type inference fails. I could have understood type inference failing for `I` in that case but it actually fails for `T`, which seems bizarre since it actually still knows that `n` is a `number`.

Can anyone help me understand why that type annotation matters and why it would fail in this way without it?

Comment: It's the poor interplay between contextual type inference and generic type inference.  The answer to the other question goes into detail. See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38872

Comment: Thanks @jcalz, that looks pretty similar to my problem here. I guess the workaround then is to specify a type, which isn't great.